# Updating Multiple User Interfaces on Data Updation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My app is Php/CodeIgniter/JQuery based and In my web application I have multiple users logged into the app. Each user has its own User Interface.

Now, all users perform their work and there is an Admin Panel. I want that when some user perform some work the Admin Panel be updated.

Currently I am constantly fetching the data through AJAX and updating the UI. My intent is if data is updated then the User Interfaces be updated without constantly fetching data through AJAX.

I try :

```
setInterval('getUpdatedData();', 30000);
```

But it is overwhelming my page.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: setInterval('getUpdatedData();', 30000);  through this i m fetching the data through ajax. but it is overwhelming my page